# Connections leak from a Psycopg connection pool

Tags: python, psycopg3

Connections leak with resulting timeout error at the connection get. I am using connection pool configured as follows:

```
from psycopg_pool import ConnectionPool

pool = ConnectionPool(conninfo=config['postgres']['url'])

@atexit.register
def pool_close():
    pool.close()
```

Then I use the pool's connections to query like this:

```
def load_smth(...):
    with pool.getconn() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
           cur.execute("select cfg from ...",(..))
           return smth
```

The problem is that at 5th request the connection pool doesn't return a connection and my app fails with a connection pool timeout error:

> psycopg_pool.PoolTimeout: couldn't get a connection after 30.0 sec

SQL queries are OK, tested with the PostgreSQL server. Moreover, if I reorder queries, failed query works. So it's a problem of getting a connection from the pool.

**upd**

After some research I tried to use a wrapper to commit after each call, in the following way:

```
def run_cursor(sql, params=(), callback=lambda x: x):
    with pool.getconn() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
           res = callback(cur.execute(sql, params))
           conn.commit()
           cur.close()
           return res
```

But connections are still leaking out from the pool.

Comment: I changed the tag `from psycopg_pool import ConnectionPool` is from `psycopg(3)` not `psycopg2`.

Comment: From docs [ConnectionPool](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html#psycopg_pool.ConnectionPool): The default for `min_size=4` and is `max_size=None`.  Then further on: *max_size (int, default: None) – The maximum number of connections the pool will hold. If None, or equal to min_size, the pool will not grow or shrink.*. So you are getting to the max(4) connections and then failing. You will need to tweak either the `min_size` or `max_size`.

Comment: FYI, you can use `pool.resize(min_size, max_size=None)` to change the pool size on the fly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. The problem is that connections seem not returned to the pool after a simple select (not change!). I studied materials and docs, tried to add commit in the way I stated in the udated question, but still no success

Comment: I was not paying enough attention. Since you not using the pool as context manager it is your responsibility to return the connections to the pool. You need to add a `pool.putconn()` after the `cur.execute("select cfg from ...",(..))` in the first example and the `cur.close()` in the second. If you are doing just  a `SELECT`(that is not doing something with side effects like calling a function) you don't need the `commit()`. I would suggest using the pool as a context manager as shown here [pool](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html).

Comment: Could you please explain how to use it as a context manager?

Comment: It s is shown in link I posted as update to my comment. Short version `with pool.connection() as con: ...` for automatically returning a connection. For pool as whole `with ConnectionPool(...) as pool:`

Comment: Thank you very muh, now it's working as expected.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver could you write up your commented solution as an answer? Hopefully Dmitry will accept it, but even if not, it would be easier for others to find the solution that way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you not using the pool as context manager it is your responsibility to return the connections to the pool. You need to add a `pool.putconn()` after the `cur.execute("select cfg from ...",(..))` in the first example and the `cur.close()` in the second. If you are doing just a SELECT(that is not doing something with side effects like calling a function) you don't need the commit(). I would suggest using the pool as a context manager as shown here [pool](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html).

Short version:

`with pool.connection() as con: ...`

for automatically returning a connection.

For pool as whole:

`with ConnectionPool(...) as pool:`

Comment: Yes, doc state that one should use .connection() instead of .getconn() but I doubt issue comes from that. I have similar issue with context as he seems to have.

Comment: @comte. The issue, from the docs [pool](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html): *getconn ... After using this function you must call a corresponding putconn(): failing to do so will deplete the pool. A depleted pool is a sad pool: you don’t want a depleted pool.* So either you do pool management manually by using `putconn()` or you use the  context manager form `with pool.connection() as con:` and let the manager take care of returning connections to the pool.

Comment: yes but the sentence just before tells you to use preferably .connection() (ie context): _You should preferably use connection(). Use this function [.getconn()] only if it is not possible to use the connection as context manager._

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is? The basics are a) If you use the context manager you don't need to use `getconn` and `putconn`, the manager will take care of that for you. b) If you don't use the context manager then you are in charge of supplying a `putconn` to put  back the connection fetched with `getconn` c) In the Op's question they where using `getconn` without using `putconn` to return the connections and ended up depleting the connection pool.

Comment: I'm using connext and have this issue, but I suspect it comes from my pool of long-standing connections that get closed one by one as time pass. I may be wrong since I didn't dig into psycopg source (for instance from what I read pool does not check connections state and do not replace closed connections), but I'm currently testing, I increased feedback level. I'll let you know if my suspition is correct.

Comment: In that case you need to create a new SO question that addresses that issue, which is different from this issue. Supply the code the you are using and the errors you are getting in the new question, not here.